# Using conditions in joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've below 3 tables from which need to fetch address for the records.

**1. Address AD**
 ---> It has all the address values(addrline1,addrline2,state,etc..) alongwith AddressID column

**2. Address_Employee AE**
 ---> It has EmpID,AddressID,AddressTypeID columns
There can be multiple instances of same EmpID with different AddressID and AddressTypeID value as either 3 or 1

**3. Address_Type AT**
 ---> There are 2 rows, with AddressTypeID and AddressType columns. AddressTypeID value with 1 will be Home and 3 will be Postal.

Need to fetch records in such a way that first need to look for Postal address, if not available then Home.

I'm using the query:

```
SELECT (AD.sAddressLine1+' '+AD.sAddressLine2+' '+AD.sSuburb+' '+AD.sPostCode) AS Address
from Address AD
INNER JOIN Address_Employee AE ON AD.AddressID = AE.AddressID 
INNER JOIN Address_Type AT ON AE.AddressTypeID= AT.AddressTypeID
```

But how can I apply the condition: "first need to look for Postal address, if not available then Home."

Please advise.

Thanks, Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view delivering the preferred address for every EmpID, and use this for furthor joins.

```
Create View V_Emp_With_Preferred_Address as

Select Distinct EmpID
,Case when Exists(Select * from Address_Employee where Address_Employee.EmpID=e.EmpID and AddressTypeID=3) then
    ( -- take preferred postal address if available
     Select ISNULL(sAddressLine1+' ','')+ISNULL(sAddressLine2+' ','')+ISNULL(sSuburb+' ','')+ISNULL(sPostCode,'')
     from Address_Employee 
     join Address on Address.AddressID=Address_Employee.AddressID
     where Address_Employee.EmpID=e.EmpID and AddressTypeID=3
     )
else 
    (
     Select ISNULL(sAddressLine1+' ','')+ISNULL(sAddressLine2+' ','')+ISNULL(sSuburb+' ','')+ISNULL(sPostCode,'')
     from Address_Employee 
     join Address on Address.AddressID=Address_Employee.AddressID
     where Address_Employee.EmpID=e.EmpID and AddressTypeID=1
     )
end as Address
from dbo.Address_Employee e
```